# Seminal papers about analysis and application based on publicly released data

Tags: data-mining, bigdata, social-network-analysis

The US government releases a lot of varied data [here](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset). Data science and data analytics have greatly matured over the last decade varying from Cambridge Analytica on one extreme to Google/Amazon Ads recommenders on another. A great number of startups have sprouted with regards to crunching big data which is already growing bigger every minute and computing some models using which prediction or recommendation services are designed. I am interested in knowing about seminal academic papers where researchers picked a societal dataset and their analysis launched big ideas and startups or at least gave novel, intelligent insights into societies. Could you list some such papers or guide where to look?